# QGIS Metatools error

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, metadata

I haven't been able to successfully use the QGIS MetaTools plugin for describing metadata. Has anyone used it before?
When I try to create metadata for a shapefile, the plugin creates the xml file but then I get a python error:

```
An error has occured while executing Python code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/daniel/.qgis2/python/plugins\metatools\metatools.py", line 267, in doEdit
standard = MetaInfoStandard.tryDetermineStandard(self.metaProvider)
File "C:/Users/daniel/.qgis2/python/plugins\metatools\standard.py", line 35, in tryDetermineStandard
print "TryDetStd ", text, " Text"
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

I'm using QGIS 2.4.0-Chugiak Chugiak, installed from the OSGeo4W installer with python version 2.7.4. Has anyone seen this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered the same issue in QGIS 2.4 x64 on Windows 7. Following a comment on the [qgis-user list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.qgis.user/28104) I can confirm that having the Python console open whilst running Metatools seems to stop the error from occurring. I don't know why at this stage though!

UPDATE: The Python Console doesn't need to be open when running Metatools, it merely needs to have been opened (and can immediately be closed) in the current QGIS session...

UPDATE #2: Commenting out line 35 in metatools\standard.py (the offending line in the error message) prevents the error from occuring, and to date hasn't affected the working of the tool

Comment: Confirmed. Just tested Metatools after opening (and closing) the Python console and the plugging worked. Is there a place we could report this as a bug so it gets fixed?

Comment: I have looked myself and not found an obvious location. Note that I can correct the bug in the plugin code now (see answer - update #2) and I'll try to get the repository updated via a Github pull request to the repository.

Comment: I have made the change noted in my answer above and submitted a pull request to the owner of the plugin.